# Numpy: search for the first matching row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have a numpy array like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[0,2]])
```

How can I return the index of the first row that matches `[0,2]`?

For lists it's easy using `index`:

```
[[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[0,2]]

l.index([0,2])
> 1
```

And I know `numpy` has the function `numpy.where`, but I'm not really sure what to make of the output of `numpy.where`:

```
np.where(x==[0,2])
> (array([0, 1, 1, 3, 3]), array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1]))
```

There's also `numpy.argmax`, but that also doesn't return what I'm looking for, which is simply the index `1`

```
np.argmax(x == [0,2], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the search list is `[0,2]`, you would bring in [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) when compared against `x`, giving us a mask of the same shape as `x`. Since you are looking for an exact match, you would look for rows with all `TRUE` values with [`.all(1)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html). Finally, you want the first index, so use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`np.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) and select the first element. The implementations as sample runs would be -

```
In [132]: x
Out[132]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 2]])

In [133]: search_list = [0,2]

In [134]: np.where((x == search_list).all(1))[0][0]
Out[134]: 1

In [135]: np.nonzero((x == search_list).all(1))[0][0]
Out[135]: 1
```